# Sorting a MultiDecimal Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I am trying to sort an array with multiDecimal

What I have so far is an array:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 20 )
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 3, [1] => 30 )
)
```

What I want to do is sort them like:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => 3, [1] => 30 )
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 20 )
)
```

I was looking on stackOverflow and it has alot of examples of using usort or uasort but I find the example exact to that problem and not enough commenting to explain the use.

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the sub arrays as first values in descending order and second values in ascending order? Or just sorting the sub arrays by greatest values?

Comment: Well, just thinking now, I no longer need to sort it from last to first. I am looking now to do just to sort the sub arrays second value, while keeping the first ID with it.

Comment: Altered the original post to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usort` function is the best for you.
Just pass this function as Callback:

```
$sorter = function($leftArray, $rightArray) {
    if ($leftArray[1] == $rightArray[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($leftArray[1] > $rightArray[1]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I assumed you want to sort by the value with index 1. If not just change the Index.

Comment: Sorry, this multi array thing is new to me. I have an array at the comment called $SolScores and that = the array above in that variable. Could you tell me how I would apply that to yours?

Comment: Any help on implementing your example?

Comment: I tried $sorted = usort($scores, "mysort"); function I called the above example and it returns 1. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Use the function this way `usort($scores, $sorter);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used the following code:

print_r($scores);
  $sorter = function($leftArray, $rightArray) {
    if ($leftArray[1] == $rightArray[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($leftArray[1] > $rightArray[1]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
};
  usort($scores, $sorter);
  print_r($scores);

And this was the output:

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 24 ) [1] =>[1] => Array ( [0] => 7 [2] => 33 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 24 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 24 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 24 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 33 ) )

Comment: Thanks for the help Learned alot :)